# using resample to aggregate data with different rules for different columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, resampling

I have a dataframe of the classic "open high low close volume" data type, so common in finance. With each row being 1 minute. 720 rows. I gather it with this code from Kraken:

```
import urllib.request, json 

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.kraken.com/0/public/OHLC?pair=XXBTZEUR&interval=1") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

columns=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'vwap', 'volume', 'ount']
data_DF=pd.DataFrame(data['result']['XXBTZEUR'],columns=columns)
data_DF['open']=data_DF['open'].astype(float)
data_DF['high']=data_DF['high'].astype(float)
data_DF['low']=data_DF['low'].astype(float)
data_DF['close']=data_DF['close'].astype(float)
data_DF['volume']=data_DF['volume'].astype(float)
data_DF['vwap']=data_DF['vwap'].astype(float)
data_DF['ount']=data_DF['ount'].astype(int)
data_DF['time']=pd.to_datetime(data_DF['time'],unit='s')
data_DF.set_index('time',inplace=True)
```

I now need to aggregate it for different time periods. To keep things simple let us suppose just the classic 5 minutes. Each column must be generated according to a different rule:
The open column must be the first falue of the open column values of the sample;
The close column must be the last value of the close column values of the sample;
the high must be the max of the high column values of the sample;
the low must be the min of the low column values of the sample;

I tried

```
data_DF5=data_DF['vwap'].resample('5Min').OHLC()
```

but it creates a series of open high low close for each column. Hmm, not what I was looking for.

I tried:

```
data_DF5=data_DF['time'].resample('5Min')
data_DF5['volume']=data_DF['volume'].resample('5Min').sum()
data_DF5['open']=data_DF['open'].resample('5Min').first()
data_DF5['close']=data_DF['close'].resample('5Min').last()
data_DF5['high']=data_DF['high'].resample('5Min').max()
data_DF5['low']=data_DF['low'].resample('5Min').min()
```

With the intent of building the dataframe one column at a time.

And I get a

> "Unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found "
>   error which I cannot understand. If I change the first line with

```
data_DF5=data_DF['vwap'].resample('5Min').mean()
```

I get a dataframe which I cannot even interpret [see (*)].

And if I change the first line with

```
data_DF5=data_DF['vwap'].resample('5Min')
```

I get:

> 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object does not support item assignment.

I am really at a loss. I have looked for stackoverflow other questions, but none seem to cover this case. Also the [manual page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) does not seem to be clear on how to solve this.

(*)

> > 2018-12-29 07:05:00                                               3417.8   2018-12-29 07:10:00                                              3411.12  2018-12-29 07:15:00                                              3408.98  2018-12-29 07:20:00                                              3409.46  2018-12-29 07:25:00                                              3409.26  2018-12-29 07:30:00                                              2729.18  2018-12-29 07:35:00                                               3413.9  2018-12-29 07:40:00                                              2739.32  2018-12-29 07:45:00                                              3426.12  2018-12-29 07:50:00                                              3423.46  2018-12-29 07:55:00                                              3433.22  2018-12-29 08:00:00                                              3424.14  2018-12-29 08:05:00                                              3426.44  2018-12-29 08:10:00                                               3424.6  2018-12-29 08:15:00                                              3425.22  2018-12-29 08:20:00                                               3425.6  2018-12-29 08:25:00                                              3425.72  2018-12-29 08:30:00                                              3427.96  2018-12-29 08:35:00                                              3427.64  2018-12-29 08:40:00                                              3427.06  2018-12-29 08:45:00                                              3426.06  2018-12-29 08:50:00                                              3423.38  2018-12-29 08:55:00                                              3426.42  2018-12-29 09:00:00                                              3441.08  2018-12-29 09:05:00                                              3439.68  2018-12-29 09:10:00                                              3429.38  2018-12-29 09:15:00                                              3422.12  2018-12-29 09:20:00                                               3418.4  2018-12-29 09:25:00                                                 3419  2018-12-29 09:30:00
> >     3415.94 
> >                                                   ... 2018-12-29 17:05:00                                              3363.46 2018-12-29 17:10:00                                              3364.86 2018-12-29 17:15:00                                              3362.56 2018-12-29 17:20:00                                              3360.88 2018-12-29 17:25:00                                              3358.98 2018-12-29 17:30:00                                               3353.8 2018-12-29 17:35:00                                              3371.62 2018-12-29 17:40:00                                              3365.38 2018-12-29 17:45:00                                              3368.76 2018-12-29 17:50:00                                              3373.82 2018-12-29 17:55:00                                              3373.32 2018-12-29 18:00:00                                              3374.78 2018-12-29 18:05:00                                              3372.56 2018-12-29 18:10:00                                               3370.3 2018-12-29 18:15:00                                               3370.3 2018-12-29 18:20:00                                              3371.36 2018-12-29 18:25:00                                              3372.14 2018-12-29 18:30:00                                              3367.36 2018-12-29 18:35:00                                               3371.3 2018-12-29 18:40:00                                              3367.08 2018-12-29 18:45:00                                               3363.3 2018-12-29 18:50:00                                              3357.66 2018-12-29 18:55:00                                              3357.64 2018-12-29 19:00:00                                              3357.64 2018-12-29 19:05:00                                                 3356 volume                 time 2018-12-29 07:05:00     0.112311
> >     2018-12-... open                   time 2018-12-29 07:05:00    3418.9
> >     2018-12-29 ... close                  time 2018-12-29 07:05:00
> >     3416.8 2018-12-29 ... high                   time 2018-12-29 07:05:00    3418.9 2018-12-29 ... low                    time 2018-12-29 07:05:00    3416.8 2018-12-29 ... Name: vwap, Length: 150, dtype: object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Grouper.html)

```
data_DF = data_DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min')).agg({'open':'first',
                                                        'close':'last',
                                                        'high':'max',
                                                        'low':'min'})

                       open   close    high     low
time                                               
2018-12-29 07:30:00  3411.4  3413.9  3413.9  3411.4
2018-12-29 07:35:00  3413.9  3413.1  3416.1  3411.9
2018-12-29 07:40:00  3413.1  3422.9  3427.5  3413.1
2018-12-29 07:45:00  3421.1  3423.8  3431.7  3418.0
2018-12-29 07:50:00  3423.8  3428.2  3428.2  3418.9
```