# pandas way of resampling VWAP data for 5 minutes from an existing data frame of 1 min that already contains VWAP data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Have a dataframe of 1 min timeseries data with

```
columns=['time', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'vwap', 'count']
```

The ohlc resampling can be done with the solution provided here:

```
data_DF = data_DF.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5min')).agg({'open':'first',
                                                        'close':'last',
                                                        'high':'max',
                                                        'low':'min'})
```

reference - [using resample to aggregate data with different rules for different columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53972633/using-resample-to-aggregate-data-with-different-rules-for-different-columns-in-a/59700449#59700449)

To resample the VWAP of 1 min to 5 mins, is there any pandas way ...

Other than recomputing vwap from the price and quantity got from the resampled 5 mts dataframe (by ignoring the vwap already existing in the 1 min dataframe).

Comment: so you want to resample `data_DF` again by 1 min ?

Comment: @YOLO, In your solution in the link above, I want to know how to include vwap in the resamping of 5min. For instance, if it is volume to be resampled, apart from ohlc, then it can be done with 'volume':'sum'. Similarly in case of 'vwap':'???'